# Hebrew (utf8) characters in windows cmd console

Tags: mysql, utf-8, hebrew, command-line

I previously asked this Q: 
[utf8 hebrew on mysql console on debian (via putty on windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/254787/utf8-hebrew-on-mysql-console-on-debian-via-putty-on-windows)
And managed to get it working by starting mysql with --default-character-set=utf8 and setting putty to show utf8 as well.

Now I need to do the same but on a windows server. The data is again the same but when I start mysql with --default-character-set=utf8 it I see multuple characters where I am supposed to see hebrew.

I think the problem is with the set up of windows cmd console that it does not properly display utf8.

any ideas ?

Comment: I ended up using phpmyadmin for those things where I need to see the hebrew...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being able to process Unicode characters is a known limitation of mysql command line client. It is addressed in [Worklog#5331](http://forge.mysql.com/worklog/task.php?id=5331), which will make it into  MySQL5.6 (or whatever version MySQL next will be). 5.5 should already support a weaker form of i18n (guessing console codepages as in [Worklog#1349](http://forge.mysql.com/worklog/task.php?id=1349)).

Comment: just to clarify, this means that i have nothing to do about it. can't access unicode data via command line on windows?

Comment: Not in interactive mode (that is, not until MySQL5.6 is out). The only way to use unicode characters in released version is non-interative (having text file with queries encoded in utf8 and use file redirection, i.e  `mysql --default-character-set=utf8 < script.sql` )

Answer (score 1):

My (admittedly limited) experience with Hebrew on Windows is that you need an actual Hebrew-localized build of Windows for it to work at all well.  I have almost always had to move files to Linux to work with them, for example.  And even if you get Hebrew to display, many programs will treat it as L-to-R instead of R-to-L.

Comment: well, it feels kind of ridiculous that I can see hebrew when connecting from my windows to a linux server but not when talking to my own windows machine.

Comment: @epeleg: You are using different software to connect to the Linux server. PuTTY's terminal emulator (which is itself emulating Xterm) is much more advanced than the built-in Win32 Console.

Answer (score 1):

You can change codepages with the `chcp` command. Multibyte UTF-8 is codepage **65001**, but its support is flaky. (For example, I tried using Python with 65001 selected, and it outright crashes on any output.)

- Make sure you are using the correct font, too.

---

If nothing else works, use the old console codepages.

The Hebrew codepage for console ("OEM") is *chcp **862*** (`--default-character-set=cp862`) and the "ANSI" one is *chcp **1255***. Make sure you have them installed under *Regional and Language Options – Advanced – Code page conversion tables*.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even if your system supporting the language, the command shell's properties showing only those 2 fonts options (Lucida Console, Raster Font), both do not support Hebrew!
using "chcp 862" will not help you yet...

In this case you might need this article, which will help you in a preview step (changing the Registry and adding other fonts to the list)

[Source](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/139/Windows-console-command-shell-Using-Local-Languages-En-US.aspx)